# weird python encoding error with elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i have run into an encoding related issue lately in python and elasticsearch which i find is weird. What happens is i have a script which downloads some data from a an api it works fine on localhost. but when i try to run the same script on my server it throws an exception

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 143: ordinal not in range(128)
```

i understand this is beecause of some non-ascii characters present in the the data downloaded. but why then same script runs on my local without throwing any error?

i cannot post complete code because its a part of bigger application and it won't make sense on its own other than these:

```
def save_data(results,index,dimension):
    def actionGenerator(results,index_name,doc_type_name):
        for i in results:
            yield {
            "_index": index_name,
            "_type": doc_type_name,
            "_source": i
            }
    res =       bulk(ES,actionGenerator(results,index,dimension),chunk_size=15000)
```

Is this error because of ES client? but in any case it works just fine on localhost
    I guess exception is being thrown here looking at traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/fbweaver/src/main/tasks/task.py", line 189, in data_dump
    parse_csv_file(FILE_NAME,REPORT_DOWNLOAD_PATH,breakdown.capitalize())
  File "/srv/fbweaver/src/main/tasks/task.py", line 128, in parse_csv_file
    save_data(result,'fb',breakdown)
  File "/srv/fbweaver/src/main/tasks/task.py", line 22, in save_data
    res =  bulk(ES,actionGenerator(results,index,dimension),chunk_size=15000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 190, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 162, in streaming_bulk
    for result in _process_bulk_chunk(client, bulk_actions, raise_on_exception, raise_on_error, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 87, in _process_bulk_chunk
    resp = client.bulk('\n'.join(bulk_actions) + '\n', **kwargs)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 143: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You might be using different python versions. Instead of letting the code implicitly convert the variables to string, use `decode` and `encode` specifically

Comment: @Alan i use exact same versions on both systems